# Not able to load new module dependency in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, carousel, steroids

Im using appgyver and are not able to load new module. I get this error message:  Failed to instantiate module legeApp due to:\n[$injector:nomod] Module 'legeApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument

Here is my code, please help!

Js file

```
angular
  .module('legeApp', ['angular-carousel'])
  .controller('IndexControllerOrer', function($scope, supersonic, $filter) {  

});
```

My Layout.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

  <title><%= yield.viewName %></title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/components/supersonic/css/supersonic.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app/common/stylesheets/application.css" />
  <link rel="import" href="/components/supersonic/components/import.html">
  <link href="/components/angular-carousel/angular-carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


  <script src="/components/angular-carousel/angular-carousel.js"></script>
  <script src="http://localhost/cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="/components/steroids-js/steroids.js"></script>
  <script src="/components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="/components/supersonic/supersonic.js"></script>
  <script src="/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>

  <% _.each(yield.modules, function(module) { %>
  <script src="/app/<%= module %>.js"></script>
  <% }); %>
</head>
<body ng-app="<%= yield.moduleName %>">

<%= yield.view %>

</body>
</html>
```

My view

```
<div ng-controller="IndexControllerOrer">

  <super-navbar>
    <super-navbar-title>
      Helseplager
    </super-navbar-title>
  </super-navbar>

          <ul class="list" rn-carousel>
            <li ng-repeat="plagerOret in plagerOret" class="item item-checkbox checkbox-assertive"  >
             <label class="checkbox">
               <input type="checkbox" ng-model="plagerOret.checked">
             </label >
              {{plagerOret.value}}
            </li>
          </ul>


<button class="button button-block button-assertive" ng-click="checkValues()" value="checkitems" >
  Diagonoser
</button>

</div>
```

The angular-carousel files is under the components/angular-carousel/angular-carousel.css and components/angular-carousel/angular-carousel.js

Comment: Is it typo or your comma is actually misplaced, in module definition

Comment: I changed it now, still got the same problem :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your javascript. It should be:

```
angular
  .module('legeApp', ['angular-carousel'])
  .controller('IndexControllerOrer', function($scope, supersonic, $filter) {      
  });
```

Comment: Is your js file loaded correctly? check the network tab?

Comment: It is in the list folder if that is what you mean? Sorry kinda new to this

Comment: No, using Chrome dev tools switch to the network tab and load the page. Check if your script is loaded. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: It looks like it does not find any of the js or css files. "ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND", which I find very strange since it does not even find the angular.js which is working

Comment: Are you sure that Angular.js is not found.

Comment: I'm able to use methods such as {{test.value}} in order to retrieve all the values in the scope, but maybe Im wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69552/discussion-between-wayne-ellery-and-thomas-m-tveten).